# KeyGen algorithm

Tags: hash, key

Can anyone find out what alghoritm was used to obtain these conversions using a key generator program?

```
37761253 - 11040171 
73425161 - 37393001 
53548859 - 59998605 
81948542 - 74536380 
16046629 - 15412670
```

Comment: I think that you hava to show more samples for somone to figure that out... A lot more...

Comment: Unfortunatlythis this is all I have. I may think about a standard hash alghoritm, maybe one that is implemented in some C libraries, but I can figure it out on my own.

Comment: The current set will result billions of hash possibilities, my humble opinion is that you can't do nothing with it. maybe deassembly the checking code but I have no clue of how doing this